Is it possible sequentially use `mysql_real_escape_string` with small chunks of a string and then reassemble the result?
I'm currently allocating the usual 2N + 1 buffer when using mysql_real_escape_string but was wondering whether I could divide the source string into multiple chunks and use a small buffer on the stack to process them in smaller steps (which would then be added to the actual query string).
I came up with this snipped (untested) but then peeked at the mariadb connector's source for mysql_real_escape_string and it seems that multi-byte characters use some special treatment and now I'm not so sure this is correct.
struct MySQLFmtBlob {
    MYSQL *mysql;
    const void *data;
    usize size;
};

template<>
struct fmt::formatter<MySQLFmtBlob> {
    constexpr auto parse(format_parse_context &ctx) {
        auto it = ctx.begin(), end = ctx.end();
        if(it != end && *it != '}')
            throw format_error("invalid format");
        return it;
    }

    auto format(const MySQLFmtBlob &blob, fmt::format_context &ctx) const {
        auto iter = ctx.out();
        MYSQL *mysql = blob.mysql; ASSERT(mysql);
        const char *ptr = (const char*)blob.data;
        usize remainder = blob.size;
        while(remainder > 0){
            constexpr unsigned long N = KB(1);
            char out[N * 2 + 1];
            unsigned long inLen = (N <= remainder) ? N : (unsigned long)remainder;
            unsigned long outLen = mysql_real_escape_string(mysql, out, ptr, inLen);
            for(unsigned long i = 0; i < outLen; i += 1){
                *iter++ = out[i];
            }
            ptr += inLen;
            remainder -= inLen;
        }
        return iter;
    }
};

EDIT: I'm aware of prepared statements but the question is not about alternatives to mysql_real_escape_string. I just want to know whether the proposed snippet (could be outside the fmt::formatter interface or w/e) would cause problems or not. I'm not asking advice on how to send queries to the server. THANKS.

Is there a reason you're not using prepared statements instead? Can completely avoid escaping strings then and it's much safer
